# Using Extended Class

Tags: java, android, class, extends

I'm new to java / object oriented language and wanted to get some help on the syntax.

I have a class defined in ConnectThread.java as

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread {
private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
    // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
    // because mmSocket is final
    BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
    mmDevice = device;

    // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
    try {
        // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); 
        tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
    mmSocket = tmp;
}



public void run() {
    // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    try {
        // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
        // until it succeeds or throws an exception
        mmSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException connectException) {
        // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException closeException) { }
        return;
    }

    // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
    //manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
}



/** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
public void cancel() {
    try {
        mmSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}
}
```

From here I tried to create a thread and connect this thread by writing this code in my connect method:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
BluetoothDevice targetdevice;
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) 
{
// Loop through paired devices
    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) 
    {
         if (device.getName().equals("HC-06"))
            targetdevice = device;
    }
}
Thread writeThread = new Thread();
writeThread.ConnectThread(targetdevice);
```

I get the error in the last line and it says "The method ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice) is undefined for the type Thread"
I thought since ConnectThread is an extended class of Thread, I could use the methods under it. Is this not the case? What would be the right way to go about doing this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your last two strings to:

```
 Thread writeThread = new ConnectThread(targetdevice);
```

When you need to start your `ConnectThread` use `start()` method:

```
 writeThread.start(); //If you need start run() method of ConnectThread.
```

Comment: Oh this works! So am I correct to assume that the method that has the same name as the class name is run whenever that object is created?

Comment: And also is writeThread.start() the same as writeThread.run() ?

Comment: writeThread.start() starts run() method in the new thread. You can get more info here [Class Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

Comment: method that has the same name as the class name is called constructor. You can find more info here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html